# Unity - Find a specific game object within a prefab (clone)

Tags: unity-game-engine, bolt

TLDR: If possible using Bolt, how do I tell unity to find a child of a clone and not find the original. Essentially, find a child within THIS GameObject (clone), not the original prefab

Hello. I am pretty new to Unity but have been making progress using Bolt. What I have is a system that will assign a random material to a plane (Being the eye of the character) when the character is instantiated. The plane is a child of the head bone. There are two planes, a left eye and a right eye.

Left Eye Randomizer

[image]

This works well enough, but I have to create a system that copies the material from the left eye to the right eye. because if I reused the code then I would get two different random eyes. I used Find GameObject, but if I have more than one character, it will find any of that Gameobject rather than the one that is a child of clone.

Right Eye Copy Left Eye

[image]

I apologize if I did not explain this the best, but I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bolt just is a visual graph using the exact same types and API.

=> Same in code or in Bolt you would rather use [`Transform.Find`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Find.html) which different to [`GameObject.Find`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html) does **not** search the entire scene but rather only **direct children** under the given `Transform` component.